# Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the currernt JSON array. While using near_duplicate_code_detector

Tags: python, json, duplicates

I haven't made any changes to the near-duplicate-code-detector, so my logic is it must be the layout of my json file.

near duplicate code detector: https://github.com/microsoft/near-duplicate-code-detector

layout of json file:

```
[
{
'filename': 'someFileName', 
'tokens': ['a', 'bunch', 'of', 'tokens']
},
{
'filename': 'someFileName2', 
'tokens': ['a', 'bunch', 'of', 'different', 'tokens']
},
]
```

full error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Comment: JSON uses double quotes `"`, what you have is not JSON.